# how to operate checkboxes with all conditions in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

***I want a jquery condition which will handle the following scenarios -***

1) Some of the checkboxes selected

2) All of the checkboxes selected

I want them both in a single loop. Currently, I've the following code to ***select all checkboxes*** only -

```
$('.check-all').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).is(':checked') ? ':not(:checked)' : ':checked';
    var ids = [];

    $('#chkall input[type="checkbox"]' + selector).each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
        ids.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    var id = [];
    id = JSON.stringify(ids);
    document.cookie = "ids="+id;
});
```

And taking checkboxes in my PHP code as -

```
echo '<ul class="list-unstyled" id="chkall">';
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    echo '<li>
    <div class="checkbox" id="checkboxes">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="'.$contact['cust_id'].'" id="'.$contact['cust_id'].'">'.$contact['cust_fname'].' '.$contact['cust_lname'].'</label>
    </div>
</li>';
}
```

So, how should I handle both scenarios in a single loop ? I've send a cookie when checking is done.

Comment: Will you mind sharing a fiddle of the same ? We do not have `$contacts ` with us..

Comment: Do you use angularjs or not ? if not, don't put the tag please.

Comment: sorry for that, I've just removed it from tags

Comment: You should need to iterate through the whole collection of checkboxes within that `#chkall` UL element. If it matches the `:checked` state, then add it to your `ids` collection.

Comment: tried, but not worked

Comment: are you just trying to create button (checkbox) that will select or unselect all other checkboxes within a page?

Comment: yeah, it's required Initially! Then I can process further. Anyway, I got the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I found a solution & now doing this in a following way -***

PHP Code -

```
echo '<ul class="list-unstyled" id="chkall">';
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    echo '<li>
    <div class="checkbox" id="checkboxes" onclick="getID('.$contact['cust_id'].')">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" name="case" value="'.$contact['cust_id'].'" id="'.$contact['cust_id'].'">'.$contact['cust_fname'].' '.$contact['cust_lname'].'</label>
    </div>
</li>';
}

<div class="checkbox" onclick="getID('0')">
    <?= Html::checkbox(null, false, [
        'id' => 'selectall',
        'label' => 'Select all',
        'class' => 'check-all',
        ]);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the respective script is -

```
var ids = [];
function getID(id) {
    var checkboxlist = document.getElementsByName('case');
    var itr = 0, checkedFlag = 0, uncheckedFlag = 0;
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('check-all');
    if (id == 0) {
        $(".check-all").prop("checked", $("#selectall").prop("checked"))
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
            if (inputElements[i].value == id) {
                if (inputElements[i].checked == true) {
                    inputElements[i].checked = false;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    inputElements[i].checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (itr < checkboxlist.length) {
            if (checkboxlist[itr].checked == true) {
                checkedFlag++;
            }
            else {
                $("#selectall").prop("indeterminate", true);
                uncheckedFlag++;
            }
            itr++;
        }
        if (checkedFlag == checkboxlist.length) {
            $("#selectall").prop("indeterminate", false);
            $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if (uncheckedFlag == checkboxlist.length) {
            $("#selectall").prop("indeterminate", false);
            $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
}
```

***That's it !!!***